# dovecot Invalid password in passdb: Not a valid MD5-CRYPT or PLAIN-MD5 password

Tags: mysql, unix, imap, mail-server, dovecot

I am migrating imap-courier to dovecot, I use openbsd+postfix+imap-courier, and now I'm trying to run openbsd+opensmtpd+dovecot.

In the beginning it was a little traumante but it works OpenSMTPD correctly.

Now I have configured dovecot, and I hope that your backend authorization is the same database that was used imap-courier.

```
In /var/log/maillog receipt the following error
auth-worker(2915): Error: sql(user@domain.tld,199.254.238.134): `Invalid password in passdb: Not a valid MD5-CRYPT or PLAIN-MD5 password`
```

My /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext

```
password_query = \
  SELECT login, password \
  FROM users WHERE login = '%u'
```

My database MySQL to start as well

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE mail;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> use mail
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE domains (
    ->        id       INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->        domain   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE users (
    ->        id       INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->        login    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    ->        name     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ->        password CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
    ->        uid      SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 2000,
    ->        gid      SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 2000,
    ->        home     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '/var/vmail',
    ->        maildir  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ->        quota    VARCHAR(10)  NOT NULL DEFAULT '10000000S');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE alias_maps (
    ->        id       INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->        account  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    ->        alias    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> GRANT SELECT ON mail.* to 'vmail'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'vmail';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Not for me this past this error to insert data in the database, I do this:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO users (login, name, password, maildir)
    -> VALUES ('name@domain.tld', 'name lastname', ENCRYPT('pass'),
    ->         'domain.tld/name/');
```

Which helps me is well received

Thanks for all

Comment: Is there a question here?  And this seems to be more about server configuration than programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using CRYPT to encrypt the password, you must put the following in dovecot-sql.conf.ext

```
default_pass_scheme = CRYPT
```

I hope this can help more people, in addition to leave you as I did my query:

```
password_query = \
  SELECT password \
  FROM users WHERE login = '%u'
```

Comment: My `dovecot-sql.conf.ext` Looks like this now after adding `default_pass_scheme` ```default_pass_scheme = CRYPT
driver = mysql
connect = host=localhost dbname=cyberpanel user=cyberpanel password=4oTCHF89uT6OKB port=3306
password_query = SELECT email as user, password FROM e_users WHERE email='%u';
user_query = SELECT '5000' as uid, '5000' as gid, mail FROM e_users WHERE email='%u';```   Even after adding that, I am facing same error

Answer (score 0):

Shoul be:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO users (login, name, password, maildir)
    -> VALUES ('name@domain.tld', 'name lastname', **MD5**('pass'),
    ->         'domain.tld/name/');
```